# EF7 sqlite create table if not exists

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

using c# entity framework 7 with sqlite, how can I check to see if a table exists and if not create it? Maybe based off a dbset that is in the context? There is no existing database with a migration or anything. The app just creates the database when its not there and I'd like to to also create the tables.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Value> Values { get; set; }


    protected override async void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=data.db");

        //here somewhere?
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use migrations, this is not an EF question. You have to write raw SQL statements to check the existence of the table (which isn't trivial with Sqlite!) and to create it. You *can* use the EF context, of course, but merely as a vehicle to execute SQL.

Comment: is there a way i could supply an sql string to the context to execute?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using migrations, you can use this in your app startup procedure:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Or with Migrations:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```